# Javascript custom prng successive calls produces 0

Tags: javascript, random

I'm trying to port the old C standard `rand()` function over to JavaScript just for testing purposes. I don't plan to use this in a practical scenario so please don't freak out about it being insecure.
This is the C implementation of the function:

```
seed = seed * 1103515245 + 12345;
return (seed/65536) % 32768;
```

Where 32768 was `RAND_MAX`. So I tried porting that over to Javascript:

```js
Random = function(p) {
  this.s = p;
  this.rand = function() {
    this.s = this.s * 1103515245 + 12345;
    return Math.floor((this.s / 65536) % 32768);
  };
};

let r = new Random(Math.floor(new Date() / 1000));
console.log(r.rand()); // gives expected results
console.log(r.rand()); // second call produces 0
```

When I call `r.rand()` the first time, it produces the expected result. But then every successive call to `r.rand()`just gives me 0 and I'm curious as to why…

Comment: My guess without looking into it is the math is failing with the huge numbers.

Comment: Hmm do you think it's the RAND_MAX value 32768? Where if any seed is larger it produces weird results? When I run the code in my C application though as long as the seed is under sizeof(int) the function works.. @epascarello you just gave me an idea, I'll try something!

Comment: When the number gets an exponent it is breaking. I am not a JavaScript numbers wizard so not sure exactly why mod with an exponent freaks out.

Comment: @epascarello Your theory was correct. Because in C integer overflows just circle the bits back around where as javascript I don't believe that happens. So adding a % this.s = this.s * 1103515245 + 12345; with 2^32-1 worked..

Comment: Your number is going way over https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER

Comment: @Nina. If you have a solution that works then please add an answer.

Comment: Yes @LeeTaylor I just realised now that the bits aren't restrained as they are in C with datatypes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was that this line `this.s = this.s * 1103515245 + 12345;` was dramatically increasing the value of `this.s` so by adding a modulus of 2<sup>32</sup> – 1 the number is restrained to produce the expected results as they would in C.

```
rand() {
  this.seed = (this.seed*1103515245 + 12345) % 4294967295;
  return (this.seed / 65536) % 32768;
}
```

It's probably not the best solution but it did seem to solve it.
A modulus [`Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) would work as well in this case,  however since the goal was to keep it synced with C, 2<sup>32</sup> – 1 works okay.

Comment: Good spot. It's a subtlety of js that I hadn't fully spotted.